# How to add a line instead of a space when pressing enter in textarea?

Tags: php, html, textarea

I've got a `textarea` form that shows new lines when users press `enter`, however as a `$_POST` variable it saves the `enters` as spaces. How can I change this so that when a user presses enter it inserts a non-breaking space in the textarea, rather than a single space?

Example:

```
document.onPresskeySpace(insertBrElementInTextarea);
```

For people who don't know how a textarea look like, this is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="process-page.php">
              <input autocomplete="off" style="height: 60px; width: 95%; margin-left: 2.5%; box-sizing: border-box" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"><br>
              <textarea autocomplete="off" required="" style="min-height: 50px; max-height: 275px; width: 95%; margin-left: 2.5%; box-sizing: border-box" class="form-control" name="msg"></textarea><br>
              <button style="width: 95%; margin-left: 2.5%; box-sizing: border-box" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Publish</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: You want to add a line by adding a **non-breaking space**? That doesn't make any sense

Comment: Showing some code would be a good starting point

Comment: No, it doesn't, a non-breaking space **prevents** line breaks

Comment: No, it isn't: it's in the name **NON-BREAKING** space. It does not produce/insert a new line character.

Comment: The newly added code **does** work with the code provided in the answers. You need to show how you process/save/store/output it as well

Comment: Because that is where your problem lies. The code above does produce `\n` at new lines

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they didn't save "enter" as a "space", they save it as "\n" (new line)

-- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages

It's quite confusing for some, because this character not showing in the database software or phpmyadmin.

I have a suggestion for it.

If you want to show it in your web using php, you could always change this character (\n) into `<br/>`

```php
...
<php echo str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $your_variable); ?>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

### For clarification purposes

A non-breaking space is **not** the terminology that you should be using a non-breaking space (html entity: `&nbsp;`) does not insert a line break. It does the opposite: i.e. it prevents a line break between two words...

For exampe suppose you wanted to make sure that a persons name didn't break to a new line half way though you would use something like:

```
firstname&nbsp;lastname
```

In this scenario the full name will *always* be on one line; in the event that any part of it needs to be *broken* to a new line then the *whole* will be placed on the new line.

**Example**

```
// Given the string
Hello there, my name is James&nbsp;Mason

// If the line limit is 30 characters (i.e. part way through the name then it'll output as
Hello there, my name is 
James&nbsp;Mason

// If the string were not to have a non-breaking space
Hello there, my name is James Mason

// The output would be
Hello there, my name is James
Mason
```

Further information can be found here:

[Wikipedia: Non-breaking Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

### How to fix

Assuming that you are entering text into a standard text area in a form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea name="inputText"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Text">
</form>
```

Then when you press enter (as stated by @HaniefHan) the character entered is `\n` which you can't usually see **and** in HTML isn't output. For example:

```
echo "this is a
sentence that spans
over multiple lines";
```

Will output on one line as:

> this is a sentence that spans over multiple lines

You can, however, still see the raw text (on the separate lines) if you:

1. Look at the page source code
2. Output the text inside of `<pre>` tags

However, as we tend to output textual data inside of html tags (e.g. `<div>...</div>`) it will appear all on one line; assuming that the screen width is greater than the text length.

If you want to display the line-breaks in the HTML then you need to replace the `\n` with `<br>` or, depending on your use case, wrap paragraphs with `<p>` (or alternative tag).

```
// Using the example form from earlier
echo str_replace("\n", "<br>", $_POST["inputText"]);
```

**Complete code example**

```
echo "
    <form method='post' action=''>
        <textarea name='inputText'></textarea>
        <input type='submit' value='Send Text'>
    </form>
";

echo str_replace("\n", "<br>", $_POST["inputText"]);
// OR
# echo nl2br($_POST["inputText"]);
```

Entered text:

```
This is text with
multiple lines
of
input text.
```

Raw Output:

```
This is text with<br>multiple lines<br>of<br>input text.
```

Shown as:

> This is text with
> multiple lines
> of
> input text.

Comment: @user838018 right, if you have a standard text area this **does** work. If you haven't then try actually showing us the code?... I have literally provided you the code to **prove** that this does work